# Error displaying geojson features

Tags: javascript, node.js, geojson

When I open the index.html from local path "file://desktop/index.html", it shows correctly. 
But when I open the file by node.js in "localhost:8080", I got an error: "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'usStates.features')" 
Can someone help me?

```
 d3.json("us.json", function(usStates) {
                  console.log(usStates.features);
      svg.selectAll("path")
               .data(usStates.features)
               .enter()
               .append("path")
               .attr("d", path)
               .style("stroke", "#fff")
               .style("stroke-width", "0.4")
               .style("fill", "rgb(213,222,217)" )
                   .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
                   var name = d.properties.name;
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRnhm.png)

Here is my server setting. I think that might be the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var fs = require('fs');
var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./config/config.json');
```

Comment: perhaps your node "server" isn't serving `us.json` correctly - check in the developer tools network tab to see what you are getting in the `us.json` request

Comment: Here is my server settingfunction handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

Comment: Yeah, great ... **check in the developer tools network tab to see what you are getting in the us.json request**

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new in node. So what you mean "developer tools network tab"?

Comment: oops, sorry, didn't see the node tag - thought this was browser issue

Comment: var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var fs = require('fs');
var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./config/config.json');

Comment: You mean these tags, right?

Comment: what? I'm talking about the tags on the question ... javscript node.js geojson ... I didn't realise the first bit of code was also in node.js and that there's no browser involved in this problem ... which is odd, because what are you using to open index.html if not a browser?

Comment: Oh, I understand now ... developer tools network tab, I forgot to be specific - that has nothing to do with node.js, that's a browser tool for developers - you can see the requests and responses in the network tab, to check that the data (us.json in this case) is what you expect it to be.